# Which open-source project can be used a 'showcase' for mid-size project MAKEFILE management?

Tags: c++, project-management, makefile

now i need to design/organize the source-code structure and makefiles for the next project. This is a software implemented largely by C++ and supposed to be used normally on Linux. It will include following components:

```
projecthome/3rd_party_lib_boost/ hdr and src
projecthome/3rd_party_lib_from_vendor/ hdr and src

# libraries that will use 3rd party libs
projecthome/lib_base_struct/ hdr and src
projecthome/lib_utilites/ hdr and src

# applications that will generate binaries, they depend on the above libs, these applications will be developed on after another, while the number of libraries are likely to be fixed.
projecthome/app_1/ hdr and src
projecthome/app_2/ hdr and src

# shell scripts that run the above binaries
projecthome/sh

# python scripts that analyze the logs
projecthome/py

# the configuration files that need to configure the binaries
projecthome/config

# how to build? this is the most difficult party now I need to address
projecthome/build
```

Now I need a way to organize the above files, and most importantly, the makefiles.

This is the first time that I design such an 'architecture' by myself. So I come here for advices.

I think the most convenient way is to download an open-source project's source and use it as a model. Can any one recommend a mid-size project who has similar structure as above?

oh, my project is not very large, i think it should have 10k-20k lines of c++ code

another thing is that, I hope the above components will not depend too much on each other, because at least one application will be sub-contracted to people outside of the company, I 
don't want him/her checkout the whole projecthome directory to compile.

Can anyone give me a clue ? thanks a lot!

Comment: do you insist upon using Makefiles? Otherwise I'd suggest you to use cmake (or scons, though I've not used scons myself). an example of using cmake is the project I'm working on: http://sourceforge.net/projects/crackpot/

Comment: another thing: If you are using svn version control, you can set svn:externals to "automatically" download third-party libraries (binary or source code).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some proposals regarding the **file system layout**. We use a similar approach for our own big-sized multi-platform builds.

Generally I would try to group the directory hierarchy by "logical means", not by means of vendor or open-source.

the **src** directory contains the sources (which was called "build" in your example before). You should also contain some samples there if you are shipping libraries.

regarding **3rd party** libs I would not differentiate between vendor and non-vendor 3rd party libs.

the **tools** directory should should contain your helpers. I wouldn't be to picky if it is for building, or for analyzing only the logfiles.

the **tmp_build** directory should be used for building only, so that you can quickly remove it in case that a complete re-build is necessary.

```
 projecthome
 |
 |---_src                # your own libs and applications and examples
 |   |-- config
 |   |-- app
 |   |   |-- app1
 |   |   `-- app2
 |   |-- lib
 |   |   |-- base_struct
 |   |   `-- utilites
 |   `-- samples
 |       |-- usage1
 |       `-- usage2
 |
 |-- 3rd_party           # all vendor and non-vendor 3rd party libs
 |   |-- boost
 |   |-- vendor1
 |   `-- vendor2
 |
 |-- build_tools             # all of your tools. Even it is only used for log analyze
 |   |-- build_helper_1
 |   |-- build_helper_2
 |   |-- py
 |   `-- sh
 |
 `-- tmp_build               # *temporary* build directory. Initially empty
```

**Edit**: it might also be a good convention to start the *most important* directories with an undersore (e.g. _src). This has the advantage that on most OS these directories are listed first (Explorer, or ls command).

**Edit**: the Makefiles in the "final directories" below the _src directory should all have the same distance to _src. E.g.:

```
_src/app/app1/Makefile -> distance to _src is 2
_src/app/app2/Makefile -> distance to _src is 2
_src/lib/utilities/Makefile -> distance to _src is 2
_src/lib/base_struct/Makefile -> distance to _src is 2
_src/samples/usage1/Makefile -> distance to _src is 2
_src/samples/usage2/Makefile -> distance to _src is 2
```

The reason for this "same distance" rule is that it allows you to resolve inter-directory dependencies in a generic way using relative-paths, e.g. with the following Makefile snippet for src/app/app1/Makefile:

```
PROJECT_HOME?=$(shell cd ../../.. && pwd)
```

Comment: ew, I don't like the leading underscore. I've never seen that done on windows or linux, is it a mac thing?

Comment: It's our companies cross-platform thing (Win, MacOS, Linux, Solaris, AIX). But I must confess that I didn't like it too at first. Meanwhile it think that it is ugly but useful.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an open source project as a template, I would define your own structure and build scripts so that you take full control and adapt it to your needs.

For the structure, choose a logical structure that separates generic libraries (to be shared between different applications), third party libraries and applications.  For example:

```
.
|-- app
|   |-- app1
|   |   `-- src
|   `-- app2
|       `-- src
|-- common_build
|-- lib
|   |-- lib1
|   |   `-- src
|   `-- lib2
|       `-- src
`-- third_party
    `-- boost
```

For the build tool, have a look at some advanced build tools such as:

- [Boost Build](http://www.boost.org/doc/tools/build/doc/html/index.html)
- [Scons](http://www.scons.org/)
- [Cmake](http://www.cmake.org/)
- ... etc

The advantage of these tools is that they handle complexity that you would have to implement yourself with Make.

I have experience with Boost Build.  It is used to build the Boost C++ libraries (although note that they are currently experimenting with Cmake). Boost Build automatically handles library dependencies, building of different toolchains, building of different variants (debug, release, static/dynamic linking, etc).  It is a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 0):

[Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) and [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) use Makefiles.